# Many-to-many query in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out how to do a many-to-many query in Doctrine 2 and I can't seem to find the answer. I know precisely how I'd do it in straight SQL:

```
      SELECT ma.id,
             ma.name
        FROM user u
        JOIN user_media_area uma ON uma.user_id = u.id
        JOIN media_area ma ON uma.media_area_id = ma.id
```

How would I do this same thing with Doctrine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual has some good examples:  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/query-builder.html

In your case it would look something like:

```
    // Build query
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->addSelect('user');
    $qb->addSelect('mediaArea');

    $qb->from('SomeBundle:User','user');

    $qb->leftJoin('user.userMediaArea','userMediaArea');
    $qb->leftJoin('userMediaArea.mediaArea','mediaArea');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $users = $query->getResult();
    echo $users[0]->getUserMediaArea()->getName();
```

You did not post your entity code so I had to do some guessing on how you defined the relations.  If you just have a simple ManyToMany between User and MediaArea then you can skip the UserMediaArea join.  D2 will figure it out.  And since you really only want MediaArea info I would actually reverse the query and do a select from MediaArea so User info would not need to be returned.  But I was trying to follow your original query.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. (I edited your original code somewhat, but at the time of this comment, the edit has not yet been peer reviewed.) Thanks especially for actually understanding my question and by using my entity names in your answer.

Comment: @Cerad have you any idea how to do this in native sql with result set mapping.

Comment: Sadly no.  In the few cases where I have had to use sql (for performance reasons) I do the mappings myself.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ma.id, ma.name
FROM User u 
JOIN u.media
```

User is the User entity, and u.media is the Media entity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the PHP part of it? How would that go?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT ma.id, ma.name FROM User u  JOIN u.media';
 $result = $entityManager->createQuery($sql)->getResult();

Comment: I didn't try this. Upon closer inspection, your DQL doesn't even refer to my join table. Where would your `ma` be coming from? Also, I don't have anything called `media`. I'm not sure that you read my question or proofread your answer too carefully.

Comment: @jason, u did not mention the structure of your entities in your post so Tuong just gave a sort of generalised DQL, but his DQL is totally acceptable. u.media is equivalent to u.mediaArea in your case.